# Bias of OLS estimator for longitudinal data

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, bias

Ignoring the autocorrelation in the data, OLS estimators of the regression coefficients and variance can either be underestimated or overestimated. 
My first question is about the regression coefficients. If the measurements are balanced, my intuition is that the estimators of the regression coefficients ignoring the autocorrelation would still be unbiased. If it is unbalanced, the estimators would be biased with more influence by individuals with more measurements. Is this correct and is this the only case where the bias occurs for regression coefficients estimators? 
My second question is about the variance estimator. When using OLS, the variance estimator can either be under or over estimated but I cannot figure out how to find the direction of the bias. Is there a way to tell?

Comment: OLS estimators are both unbiased and consistent in your case. But they are inefficient.

Comment: The estimated variances will be biased and inconsistent.